# RhinoCommons UnitOfWork Question with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-of-work, rhino-commons

I'm playing around with RhinoCommons and NHibernate and I had a question about the UnitOfWork pattern.

Sorry if this is a n00b question.

Should the UnitOfWork be started at the very highest level (ie the controller)? Or say in the service module that the controller is calling down into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UnitOfWorkApplication.  [Here's how](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/rhino-commons-with-ms-mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the UnitOfWork must be a service facility and not part of the Controller responsabilities.